# add a new tag to the first page beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm making a diapo for my presentation to get licence degree, I need to change somme things:
1- add the name of my professor supervisor in front of my name 
2- change the date and write the promotion "2015/2016"
3- add on the top the institut and the degree
as on the image
[image]

here the type of my document

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fine with a hackish solution:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mydefault}[1][]
{
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
        \usebeamerfont{institute} Institue and Degree
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle    
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
        \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}    
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
        \usebeamerfont{author}supervisor \hspace*{2cm} \insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
        \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
    \endgroup
    \vfill
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[mydefault][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\makeatother

\title[title for footline]{Realisation de quelque chose ...}
\subtitle{presente}
\author[name for footline]{myname}
\date[date for footline]{2015/2016}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]